# next js parsing data of wav file

Tags: file-upload, next.js13, formidable

trying to parse header of dropped wav file in next js.
on /pages/index.tsx I use new FormData to append dropped file.
when I send it back to /api/parseHeader.ts I cant seem to retrieve the information I need.

Any help would be welcome
Thank you

```
frontend:
// getting data:
let file = event.dataTransfer.files\[0\];

// sending to the back:
const body = new FormData();
body.append("file", file);

let response = await fetch("/api/musicToMyEars",{
method:"POST",
body:body,
});

backend:

import {IncomingForm} from 'formidable';

// stop default body parsing:
export const config = {
api: {
bodyParser: false,
},
}

const asyncParse = (req:NextApiRequest) =\>
new Promise((resolve, reject) =\> {
const form = new IncomingForm({ multiples: false});
form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) =\> {
if (err) return `your text`reject(err);
console.log('inside parser:')
resolve({ fields, files });
});
});

export default async function handler(
req: NextApiRequest,`your text`
res: NextApiResponse\<Data\>
) {

let result = await asyncParse(req);
res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```